# Can't install SteamCMD on my Ubuntu VM using OCI

Tags: apt, server, cloud

running Unbuntu 22.04. Was trying to download SteamCMD through the following commands. The arch is aarch64

```
sudo add-apt-repository multiverse; 
sudo dpkg --add-architecture i386; 
sudo apt update
sudo apt install steamcmd
```

Not sure what other information is needed since I have no idea what I am doing but will try to fill out more as I go!

```
~$ sudo apt update
Hit:1 http://iad-ad-1.clouds.ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports jammy InRelease
Hit:2 http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports jammy-security InRelease
Hit:3 http://iad-ad-1.clouds.ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports jammy-updates InRelease
Hit:4 http://iad-ad-1.clouds.ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports jammy-backports InRelease
Ign:5 http://iad-ad-1.clouds.ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports jammy/main i386 Packages
Ign:6 http://iad-ad-1.clouds.ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports jammy/restricted i386 Packages
Ign:7 http://iad-ad-1.clouds.ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports jammy/universe i386 Packages
Ign:8 http://iad-ad-1.clouds.ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports jammy/multiverse i386 Packages
Ign:9 http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports jammy-security/main i386 Packages
Ign:5 http://iad-ad-1.clouds.ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports jammy/main i386 Packages
Ign:6 http://iad-ad-1.clouds.ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports jammy/restricted i386 Packages
Ign:7 http://iad-ad-1.clouds.ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports jammy/universe i386 Packages
Ign:10 http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports jammy-security/restricted i386 Packages
Ign:11 http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports jammy-security/universe i386 Packages
Ign:12 http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports jammy-security/multiverse i386 Packages
Ign:8 http://iad-ad-1.clouds.ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports jammy/multiverse i386 Packages
Ign:9 http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports jammy-security/main i386 Packages   
Ign:10 http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports jammy-security/restricted i386 Packages
Ign:11 http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports jammy-security/universe i386 Packages
Ign:12 http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports jammy-security/multiverse i386 Packages
Ign:13 http://iad-ad-1.clouds.ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports jammy-updates/main i386 Packages
Ign:14 http://iad-ad-1.clouds.ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports jammy-updates/restricted i386 Packages
Ign:15 http://iad-ad-1.clouds.ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports jammy-updates/universe i386 Packages
Ign:16 http://iad-ad-1.clouds.ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports jammy-updates/multiverse i386 Packages
Ign:5 http://iad-ad-1.clouds.ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports jammy/main i386 Packages
Ign:6 http://iad-ad-1.clouds.ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports jammy/restricted i386 Packages
Ign:7 http://iad-ad-1.clouds.ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports jammy/universe i386 Packages
Ign:9 http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports jammy-security/main i386 Packages
Ign:10 http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports jammy-security/restricted i386 Packages
Ign:8 http://iad-ad-1.clouds.ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports jammy/multiverse i386 Packages
Ign:17 http://iad-ad-1.clouds.ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports jammy-backports/main i386 Packages
Ign:18 http://iad-ad-1.clouds.ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports jammy-backports/universe i386 Packages
Ign:11 http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports jammy-security/universe i386 Packages
Ign:13 http://iad-ad-1.clouds.ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports jammy-updates/main i386 Packages
Ign:12 http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports jammy-security/multiverse i386 Packages
Ign:9 http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports jammy-security/main i386 Packages
Ign:10 http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports jammy-security/restricted i386 Packages
Ign:14 http://iad-ad-1.clouds.ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports jammy-updates/restricted i386 Packages
Ign:11 http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports jammy-security/universe i386 Packages
Ign:12 http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports jammy-security/multiverse i386 Packages
Ign:15 http://iad-ad-1.clouds.ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports jammy-updates/universe i386 Packages
Ign:16 http://iad-ad-1.clouds.ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports jammy-updates/multiverse i386 Packages
Ign:5 http://iad-ad-1.clouds.ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports jammy/main i386 Packages
Ign:6 http://iad-ad-1.clouds.ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports jammy/restricted i386 Packages
Ign:7 http://iad-ad-1.clouds.ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports jammy/universe i386 Packages
Ign:8 http://iad-ad-1.clouds.ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports jammy/multiverse i386 Packages
Ign:17 http://iad-ad-1.clouds.ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports jammy-backports/main i386 Packages
Ign:18 http://iad-ad-1.clouds.ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports jammy-backports/universe i386 Packages
Ign:9 http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports jammy-security/main i386 Packages
Ign:13 http://iad-ad-1.clouds.ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports jammy-updates/main i386 Packages
Ign:14 http://iad-ad-1.clouds.ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports jammy-updates/restricted i386 Packages
Ign:10 http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports jammy-security/restricted i386 Packages
Ign:15 http://iad-ad-1.clouds.ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports jammy-updates/universe i386 Packages
Ign:11 http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports jammy-security/universe i386 Packages
Ign:12 http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports jammy-security/multiverse i386 Packages
Ign:16 http://iad-ad-1.clouds.ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports jammy-updates/multiverse i386 Packages
Ign:5 http://iad-ad-1.clouds.ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports jammy/main i386 Packages
Ign:6 http://iad-ad-1.clouds.ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports jammy/restricted i386 Packages
Ign:7 http://iad-ad-1.clouds.ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports jammy/universe i386 Packages
Ign:8 http://iad-ad-1.clouds.ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports jammy/multiverse i386 Packages
Ign:17 http://iad-ad-1.clouds.ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports jammy-backports/main i386 Packages
Ign:18 http://iad-ad-1.clouds.ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports jammy-backports/universe i386 Packages
Ign:13 http://iad-ad-1.clouds.ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports jammy-updates/main i386 Packages
Err:9 http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports jammy-security/main i386 Packages
  404  Not Found [IP: 185.125.190.39 80]
Ign:14 http://iad-ad-1.clouds.ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports jammy-updates/restricted i386 Packages
Ign:15 http://iad-ad-1.clouds.ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports jammy-updates/universe i386 Packages
Ign:10 http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports jammy-security/restricted i386 Packages
Ign:11 http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports jammy-security/universe i386 Packages
Ign:12 http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports jammy-security/multiverse i386 Packages
Ign:16 http://iad-ad-1.clouds.ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports jammy-updates/multiverse i386 Packages
Err:5 http://iad-ad-1.clouds.ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports jammy/main i386 Packages
  404  Not Found [IP: 185.125.190.39 80]
Ign:6 http://iad-ad-1.clouds.ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports jammy/restricted i386 Packages
Ign:7 http://iad-ad-1.clouds.ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports jammy/universe i386 Packages
Ign:8 http://iad-ad-1.clouds.ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports jammy/multiverse i386 Packages
Ign:17 http://iad-ad-1.clouds.ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports jammy-backports/main i386 Packages
Ign:18 http://iad-ad-1.clouds.ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports jammy-backports/universe i386 Packages
Ign:13 http://iad-ad-1.clouds.ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports jammy-updates/main i386 Packages
Ign:14 http://iad-ad-1.clouds.ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports jammy-updates/restricted i386 Packages
Ign:15 http://iad-ad-1.clouds.ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports jammy-updates/universe i386 Packages
Ign:16 http://iad-ad-1.clouds.ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports jammy-updates/multiverse i386 Packages
Ign:17 http://iad-ad-1.clouds.ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports jammy-backports/main i386 Packages
Ign:18 http://iad-ad-1.clouds.ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports jammy-backports/universe i386 Packages
Err:13 http://iad-ad-1.clouds.ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports jammy-updates/main i386 Packages
  404  Not Found [IP: 185.125.190.39 80]
Ign:14 http://iad-ad-1.clouds.ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports jammy-updates/restricted i386 Packages
Ign:15 http://iad-ad-1.clouds.ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports jammy-updates/universe i386 Packages
Ign:16 http://iad-ad-1.clouds.ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports jammy-updates/multiverse i386 Packages
Err:17 http://iad-ad-1.clouds.ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports jammy-backports/main i386 Packages
  404  Not Found [IP: 185.125.190.39 80]
Ign:18 http://iad-ad-1.clouds.ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports jammy-backports/universe i386 Packages
Reading package lists... Done
E: Failed to fetch http://iad-ad-1.clouds.ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports/dists/jammy/main/binary-i386/Packages  404  Not Found [IP: 185.125.190.39 80]
E: Failed to fetch http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports/dists/jammy-security/main/binary-i386/Packages  404  Not Found [IP: 185.125.190.39 80]
E: Failed to fetch http://iad-ad-1.clouds.ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports/dists/jammy-updates/main/binary-i386/Packages  404  Not Found [IP: 185.125.190.39 80]
E: Failed to fetch http://iad-ad-1.clouds.ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports/dists/jammy-backports/main/binary-i386/Packages  404  Not Found [IP: 185.125.190.39 80]
E: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
```

Comment: My discord is ayaya_. If anybody wants to help me there! I'm new to Ubuntu and not sure how most of it works!

Comment: *i386* is **not** a port but a main architecture, thus its sources/packages are in the archive. You've not said your architecture; but many lines provided are for *ports*, thus you're likely using *ppc64el*, *risc64* *arm64*, *armhf* etc... or a PORT, and not the main archive. To add architectures found in Ubuntu *archives* you'll need to add source lines for that.  What OS/release are you using and what architecture?  (ie. `http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports` does not contain *i386* ; you've likely used a command intended for *amd64* architecture but aren't using *amd64*)

Comment: Hi! I'm pretty sure it's Ubuntu 22.04. I'm not sure what you mean by architecture, but if you don't mind guiding me to where I'd be able to find it, I'd be able to give more information!

Comment: will do! i’m a complete beginner to this stuff and have just been following youtube videos , updated the post with what information i know i have!!

Comment: add the output of the command `arch`.

Comment: updated with the arch

Answer (score 0):

The VM you're using is based on the ARM CPU architecture (like the processors you get in a Raspberry Pi or cellphone). The `steamcmd` package is only [available](https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?keywords=steamcmd) for the i386 architecture, which is more commonly found in desktop and laptop computers.

Essentially i386 is a subset of the popular Intel and AMD "x86" architecture. As such you will not be able to install the i386 steamcmd package on this particular machine.

The solution is to start a VM which is x86-64 - the more modern 64-bit (and 32-bit compatible) version of x86.